# How to prevent my loop from printing out the same last number twice

Tags: java

My loop is designed to take a user input, and add that number to itself until it reaches a user given max number. So if the user inputs 27 to count by, and 4000 as a max number, the program will add 27 to 27 and print out each result until it reaches 4000. If the last loop will cause the program to print out a number past the max (the last iteration of 27 before 4000 is 3996, my program will print out 4023, which is 3996 + 27.) than I want it to only print out the last number that is NOT above the max, so 3996. BUT, if it ends exactly on the max number, say counting by five up until 100, I still want it to print the 100. Just cut off anything past that number. Any idea how to prevent it from doing this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Activity5
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number to count by");
    int countBy = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter maximum number");
    int maxNum = keyboard.nextInt();
    int answer = 0;
    while (answer < maxNum)
      {
        answer = answer + countBy;
          {
              if (answer > maxNum)
              {
                  System.out.println(answer - countBy);
              }
              else System.out.println(answer);
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'if' is doing you no good. I don't see how it can help you.  So your loop could be as simple as:

```
public static void main(String ...args) {
    int countBy = 27;
    int maxNum = 200;
    int answer = countBy;
    while (answer < maxNum)
    {
        System.out.println(answer);
        answer = answer + countBy;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
27
54
81
108
135
162
189
```

If you don't want to print the initial countBy number, then change this line as so:

```
int answer = 2 * countBy;
```

Comment: you beat me to it :)

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I had to edit my while statement as well to be answer <= maxNum simply so it would also print off the last number if it happened to be the max (such as printing ...95, 100) if the max was 100. I didn't have the = in my original program.

Answer (score 0):

Just move answer = answer + countBy from beginning to the end of the loop

```
 while (answer < maxNum)
      {
              if (answer > maxNum)
              {
                  System.out.println(answer - countBy);
              }
              else System.out.println(answer);

              answer = answer + countBy;
      }
```

Comment: ah.  Didn't see this before answering.  This is logically the same as my answer, but unnecessarily complex, as the **if** will never be true, and so the whole conditional can be removed.  So this answer, upon analysis that the **if** is always false, becomes my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Same as @Сергей Коновалов but instead just use one if statement without the else

```
while (answer < maxNum){
    answer = answer + countBy;
    if (answer < maxNum)
    {
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
    //answer = answer + countBy; produces a 0 as the print is run first
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition already ensures you won't go past maxNum, so simply

```
int answer = 0;
while (answer < maxNum) {
    System.out.println(answer);
    answer += countBy;
}
```

If you don't want the first number like in your example, then

```
int answer = countBy;
while (answer < maxNum) {
    System.out.println(answer);
    answer += countBy;
}
```